# Google play leaderboards not updating the score after new score has been reported

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, leaderboard

I have been struggling with this problem for a few days... I have google play services set up, my achievements work properly, but the leaderboard doesn't seem to want to work.
This is the code that reports new score to the leaderboard:

```
 public static void AddScoreToLeaderboard(string LeaderboardId, long score) {
    Social.ReportScore(score, LeaderboardId, success => { Debug.Log("Leaderboard updated: "+score); });
}
```

When the function is called i get the debug message saying that the leaderboard has been updated but when i go back to the leaderboard which i display with this:

```
public static void ShowLeaderboardsUI()
{
    Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
}
```

The leaderboard is completely empty...
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you test the value of `success` in your arrow function ? What does it say ? Is it `true` or `false` ?

Comment: Yes values return true. However i was able to find a fix to my problem just 2 mins ago :D i will post the answer which another user had suggested on a different site. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So another user on github suggested this and it worked for me.

I had same problem with my game but i resolved that.
Follow the steps carefully:
1-Go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
2-Remove all credentials
3-Go to https://play.google.com/apps/publish
4-In all applications tab click on your game
5-Then from left menu click on Release Management and then go to App signing
6-Copy the code of SHA1 from the App signing certificate part
7-Go back to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
8-Create credentials and choose OAuth client ID
9-Choose application type (it was android for me!)
10-paste the code you copied from part 6 in Signing-certificate fingerprint field
11-Write the package name of the game exactly in Package name field the click on create
12-Go back to https://play.google.com/apps/publish
13-click on Game Services and then click on your game
14-Click on Link apps from left menu
15-click on Link another app
16-Choose your platform (android for me!)
17-write a name
18-click on Package name field and choose your package name there
19-save and publish the linked app that you just created
20-compare the OAuth2 Client ID from linked app that you just created with Client ID in credentials you created in part 11
21-if they have the same code the leaderboard will work fine!
Hope it solves your problem!